# How do mainstream Christians handle the Epistle of St. Barnabas' prophecy that Jesus will return in the next 50 years?

Tags: eschatology, prophecy, extra-biblical

In the [Epistle of Barnabas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_of_Barnabas), it says

> Barnabas 15:3 Of the Sabbath He speaketh in the beginning of the
>   creation; And God made the works of His hands in six days, and He
>   ended on the seventh day, and rested on it, and He hallowed it.
>
> Barnabas 15:4 Give heed, children, what this meaneth; He ended in six
>   days. He meaneth this, that in six thousand years the Lord shall bring
>   all things to an end; for the day with Him signifyeth a thousand
>   years; and this He himself beareth me witness, saying; Behold, the day
>   of the Lord shall be as a thousand years. Therefore, children, in six
>   days, that is in six thousand years, everything shall come to an end.
>
> Barnabas 15:5 And He rested on the seventh day. this He meaneth; when
>   His Son shall come, and shall abolish the time of the Lawless One, and
>   shall judge the ungodly, and shall change the sun and the moon and the
>   stars, then shall he truly rest on the seventh day.

And we know that the World (Human History) according to Bible is now almost **6000** years.
This means The Second Coming of Jesus will happen within **50** years from now.

According to  [Saint Malachy Prophecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_of_the_Popes)
 we can know that it has the same timeline.

How should we interpret these things?

Comment: Where does the 50 years figure come from?  I've never seen a 6000-year time scale that places the year 2000 AD at around 5940...

Comment: I'm locking this because the term "Mainstream Christian" is too broad and undefined to be used to scope a question adequately by today's site standards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Epistle of Barnabas is not considered canon. Sticking purely to canon, the bible is very explicit that we *do not know*. The world could end tomorrow. Or this afternoon. Or 10,000 years from now:

**Matt 25:13**

> Watch therefore, for you know neither the day nor the hour wherein the Son of man comes.

**Mark 13:32**

> No one knows about that day or hour, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. Be on guard! Be alert! You do not know when that time will come.

**1 Thessalonians 5:2**

> for you know very well that the day of the Lord will come like a thief in the night.

Comment: If the world hasn't ended by the year 10,000 A.D., then the Y10K problem will definitely be the end of the world.

Comment: "The Epistle of Barnabas is not considered canon." +1

Comment: The term for non Canon books is [Apocrypha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrypha) There is only a slight difference in what is Canon and what is Apocrypha among most of the denominations. The most notable difference being the Catholics have 7 more books in their Bible than most Protestants. I think worth mentioning in your post to make it better and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Yet the Bible suggests support for the statement of Barnabas in this regard.  Compare Psalm 90:4 -

> For a thousand years in Thy sight are like yesterday when it passes
>   by, or as a watch in the night.

and 2 Peter 3:8 -

> …with the Lord one day is as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.

with the concept in Mark 2:27-28 that -

> Consequently, the Son of Man is Lord even of the Sabbath.

and the description of a 1000 year kingdom in Revelation chapter 20 (selections from verses 2 and 4) -

> …and bound him [Satan] for a thousand years …and [the church] reigned
>   with Christ for a thousand years.

Not explicitly stated, but enough to make the suggestion of the Epistle of Barnabas a good possibility, and suggestive that it may have been a common opinion in the early church shortly after the time of the apostles.

With regards to whether it is possible to know these things in advance, I would just suggest a couple thoughts to consider.

First, a careful reading of the passage from Mark 13:32 cited by a previous poster says that the time was not then known to anyone -

> not even the angels, nor the Son.

This does not mean that no one will ever know.  Certainly Jesus knows the time of His return before it happens.

Second, the events to which Barnabas refers are events that occur *after* Jesus returns.

Final thought: I can't help it that Bible chronology and time prophecy have gotten a bad rap because of past abuses or because people have been "told" by God or given visions of the year and day when Jesus returns.  This should not be held against the concept of Biblical time prophecy, but rather against self-important Christians who think that God speaks only to or through them.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Jesus never said he does not know the day of his return, he said he did not know the day Heaven and Earth will pass away... read things in context please... Barnabas adds up with the rest of scripture.

Mar 13:31  Heaven and earth shall pass away: but my words shall not pass away. 
Mar 13:32  But of that day and that hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels which are in heaven, neither the Son, but the Father.

Comment: This looks like just your own opinion, not an overview of mainstream Christianity.